# JavaScript access parent object attribute

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a small issue in JS, I have two nested objects, and I would like to access a variable from the parent, like so:

```
var parent = {
    a : 5,

    child: {
        b : 3,
        displayA : function(){
            console.log(this.a);
            //undefined
            },

        displayB : function(){
            console.log(this.b);
            //displays 3
            }
        }
}
```

And I would just like to know how to make parent.child.displayA work :) (I have sub-objects that need access to a parent's variable)

Any help appreciated
Thank you very much!

Comment: In the `displayA` function, you're referencing "this" and attempting to access its "a" attribute. The call to "this" here refers to the child object and not the parent. If you used a constructor you could pass in the context (this) of its parent to the child object. Or you could use the call or bind methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the value of `this`:

```
parent.child.displayA.call(parent); // 5
```

You may also be interested in [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it:

```
parent.child.displayA = function(){
  console.log(this.a);
}.bind(parent);
parent.child.displayA(); // 5
```

Or you you can just use `parent` instead of `this`:

```
parent.child.displayA = function(){
  console.log(parent.a);
};
parent.child.displayA(); // 5
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `super.prop` to access parent class properties. Of course, only if you are using ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is [prototype based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Prototype-based), it is not a regular OOP language like PHP or Java.

Take a look to [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and implement something like [Simple Javascript inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).

You could probably access to parent through `window.parent` if it is in the global scope, but your example will not work in every case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way for the object `child` to know that it is a member of the parent object. In your situation, you can make a direct reference to the parent object in `displayA()`, like so:

```
displayA : function(){
  console.log(parent.a);
}
```

You do not need to place parent in the global scope and use `window.parent` as another answer suggests; since you are declaring `displayA` within the scope of `parent`, the function will close over `parent`, and it will be accessible anywhere within `child`. Since the closure contains a reference to the `parent` object, you will see that changes to `parent` will be reflected in the behaviour of `displayA`. For example, suppose `parent` and `child` are defined as in your example, except `displayA` is modified to use `parent.a`. Then:

```
parent.child.displayA(); //=> 5
parent.a = 10;
parent.child.displayA(); //=> 10
```

All this being said, if you are trying to mimic OOP, then the other answer is right: you should read more about how the Javascript prototype chain works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't really make sence to do it like that since you can access child object only through its parent. so why add a mthod displayB to the child while you can add it to the parent which has access to all child properties.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you haven't inheritance. You may do this

```
...
    displayA : function(){
        console.log(parent.a);
        // 5
    },
...
parent.child.parent = parent;
parent.child.displayA();
```