# JavaScript access parent element

Tags: javascript, oop

I need to access a variable of a containing element in a function of the child element. How can I achieve this?

```
object = {
    a : {
        c : function() {
            //need to access b here
        },
        d : 2
    },
    b : 1
};
```

In this case I need to access the variable `b` in the function `c`. I tried some variations with `bind()` but nothing worked. The question [JavaScript access parent object attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734312/javascript-access-parent-object-attribute) doesn't work for me. I can't reach the variable `object`, because the object is deeper nested.

Comment: You'll have to pass a reference to `object` or `b` or else add a reference to `b` to the `a` object. There are no built-in back references available to go "up" an object hierarchy.

Comment: Reference using this and then call with given this context like in the linked question didn't work?

Comment: Just reference `object.b`?

Comment: These are not "elements", they are "objects". `b` is not a "variable"; it's a "property".

Comment: Here's a [test](https://jsfiddle.net/9dc3k01m/1/) on JSFiddle. Access using parent name or calling with this context works

Comment: You should read more about the scope...

Answer (score 1):

Make `a` into a getter.

```
object = {
    get a() {
      var self = this;
      return {
        c: function() {
           return self.b;
        },
        d: 2
      }
    },
    b : 1
};
```

Or, if `c` doesn't need a `this` to refer to `d`, for example, then

```
object = {
    get a() {
      return {
        c: () => this.b,
        d: 2
      }
    },
    b : 1
};
```

Comment: This has the ugly property of `object.a !== object.a`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that `object` is deeply nested. Just use `object.b`.

```js
var object;
([{a:[{b:[{c:[{d:[{e:[{f: // deeply nested
  object = {
    a: {
      c: function() {
        console.log(object.b);
      },
      d: 2
    },
    b: 1
  }
}]}]}]}]}]}])[0].a[0].b[0].c[0].d[0].e[0].f.a.c();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Oriol's answer. :-)

Another alternative to use a closure.

```js
([{a:[{b:[{c:[{d:[{e:[{f: // deeply nested
  (function (){
    var object = {
      a: {
        c: function() {
          console.log(object.b);
        },
        d: 2
      },
      b: 1
    }
    return object;
  })()
}]}]}]}]}]}])[0].a[0].b[0].c[0].d[0].e[0].f.a.c();
```

Or you can move the object creation to a separate function if that makes sense (you can name that function).

```js
function createHierarchy(){
  return ([{a:[{b:[{c:[{d:[{e:[{f:createObject()}]}]}]}]}]}]);
}

function createObject(){
    var object = {
      a: {
        c: function() {
          console.log(object.b);
        },
        d: 2
      },
      b: 1
    }
    return object;
}

var hierarchy = createHierarchy();
hierarchy[0].a[0].b[0].c[0].d[0].e[0].f.a.c();
```

Using a DI container is just a single step from here. :-P

*It may happen that you need a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) instead of a [hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy) and your model is completely wrong.*